# return the entire row with has the max value in numpy - python

Tags: numpy

```
val = np.array([[1, 3], [2, 5], [0, 6], [1, 2] ])
print(np.max(val))
6
```

I also want to print the row [0,6]. with axis it returns all the value from other rows as well. argmax doesnt return the row index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use np.where which return indexes where true:

```
r,_ = np.where(val == np.max(val))
val[r]
```

Output:

```
array([[0, 6]])
```